# artisan test command is not working, laravel 7.x

Tags: php, laravel

i hope you are doing well, so my problem is that i cannot run the artisan `test` command
whenever i run the command `php artisan test` i get the following error

```
   RuntimeException 

  Running Collision ^5.0 artisan test command requires Laravel ^8.0.

  at D:\php-files\behzad-thingi\vendor\nunomaduro\collision\src\Adapters\Laravel\Commands\TestCommand.php:71
     67▕         }
     68▕
     69▕         // @phpstan-ignore-next-line
     70▕         if ((int) \Illuminate\Foundation\Application::VERSION[0] < 8) {
  ➜  71▕             throw new RuntimeException('Running Collision ^5.0 artisan test command requires Laravel ^8.0.');
     72▕         }
     73▕
     74▕         $options = array_slice($_SERVER['argv'], $this->option('without-tty') ? 3 : 2);
     75▕
```

honestly i didint test that the command worked before, since i upgraded the dependencies to use `pestphp` and followed their installation steps [here](https://pestphp.com/docs/installation/). thanks for your answer.

Comment: The error clearly says that you need Laravel 8.0 or higher in order to use this, and you are using Laravel 7.x. So what kind of answer are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was an issue with pestphp versioning, as explained in this [here](https://github.com/pestphp/pest/issues/111). i just had to replace the version of pestphp and collision from

```
        "nunomaduro/collision": "v5.0.0-BETA3",
        "pestphp/pest": "^0.2.3",
```

to

```
        "nunomaduro/collision": "5.0.0-BETA2",
        "pestphp/pest": "0.2.1",
```